# Issue with uploading a image into mysqli database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Since I added the function to upload a image my script doesn't work anymore .. That means I can't insert new posts into the datbase.
Please help me with this issue, thanks! For more questions just use the comments section below :)

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$typ = $_POST['typ'];
$titel = $_POST['titel'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$timestamp = time();

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "...", "...", "...");
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die("Unable to connect to database: " . $db->connect_error);
}

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        // Verweis auf Bild
        $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

        // Vorbereiten für den Upload in DB
        $data = addslashes(file_get_contents($image));

        // Metadaten auslesen
        $meta = getimagesize($image);
        $mime = $meta['mime'];
}

//create a prepared statement
$stmt = $db->set_charset("utf8");
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO artikel (`red`, `typ`, `titel`, `content`, `image`, `mimetype`, `timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

//bind the username and message
$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $uname, $typ, $titel, $content, $data, $mime, $timestamp);

//run the query to insert the row
$stmt->execute();

header("Location: erfolg.php");

?>
```

html form:

```
<form name="form2" action="insert.php" method="post">
Username:<br>
<input style="width:100%;" type="text" accept-charset="utf-8" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>" class="login_form" readonly><br><br>
Typ:<br>
<input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="typ" value="blog" class="login_form" readonly><br><br>
Titel:<br>
<input style="width:100%;" type="text" placeholder="Überschrift, z.B. Die Kunst des Spickens" name="titel"><br><br>
Inhalt:<br>
<textarea style="width:100%; height:250px; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;" type="text" placeholder="Inhalt" name="content"></textarea><br><br>
Bild anhängen (maximal 1 Bild):<br>
<input name="image" type="file"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Eintragen">
</form>
```

So, this was the php and html, thanks for your help!

And sorry for the bad english

Comment: The file will not be uploaded, check your form, it is missing something

Comment: @Amit Thakur and what is missing?  as i already said i can't find the mistake in the script

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your form needs enctype="multipart/form-data" to upload files.

Second, wouldn't it be an idea to move the uploaded file from the temp dir and save the path in the database, instead of saving the complete binary data of the temporary image?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php